# Iterate over rows with same ID to fetch value on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with periods of time framed by a start and an end date in two different columns:

```
ID      Start            End            Consecutive 
001365  20 août 2021    30 sept. 2021    
001365  17 déc. 2021    23 janv. 2022   int  
001981  01 janv. 2021   31 déc. 2021     
001981  01 janv. 2022   31 déc. 2022    ok 
011492  02 déc. 2021    05 janv. 2022    
011492  06 janv. 2022   10 janv. 2022   ok  
011492  17 janv. 2022   24 janv. 2022   int 
011492  25 janv. 2022   31 janv. 2022   ok 
011492  21 févr. 2022   13 mars 2022    int 
017958  24 juin 2021    04 juil. 2021    
017958  05 juil. 2021   19 juil. 2021   ok 
017958  20 juil. 2021   31 juil. 2021   ok 
017958  23 août 2021    31 déc. 2021    int 
017958  01 janv. 2022   30 juin 2022    ok 
018244  01 juil. 2021   08 août 2021     
018244  20 sept. 2021   08 oct. 2021    int 
018244  11 oct. 2021    21 nov. 2021    int 
018244  22 nov. 2021    15 déc. 2021    ok 
018244  16 déc. 2021    07 août 2022    ok 
018422  29 nov. 2021    19 déc. 2021    ok 
018422  20 déc. 2021    31 déc. 2021    ok 
018422  01 janv. 2022   31 janv. 2022   ok 
018422  01 févr. 2022   12 août 2022    ok 
036530  01 juil. 2021   07 juil. 2021    
036530  08 juil. 2021   18 juil. 2021   ok 
036530  02 août 2021    15 août 2021    int 
036530  27 août 2021    31 déc. 2021    int 
036530  01 janv. 2022   10 juil. 2022   ok
```

A column named `Consecutive` checks if those periods are consecutive (`ok`) or not (`int`) for each ID. If there's only `ok`, I need to fetch the very first Start date and if there are one or several `int`, I need to fetch the Start date of the last `int` like so:

[image: desired df]

I could not find a similar question but maybe I'm not using the right technical terms.
Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Why is the date `01 sept. 2021` for the 6th group (`018442`)?

Comment: Also, will you please provide your input data as text, not an image? I can't copy/paste from an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like this should work for you:

```
df['New_col'] = df.loc[df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Consecutive'] == 'int', 'Start'].index[-1] if x['Consecutive'].eq('int').all() else np.nan).loc[lambda x: x[x.notna()]], 'Start']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this error :"IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0", I guess it's because the very first df row doesn't have a previous one to look into ?

Comment: @Guad Right you are! Check the answer now.

Comment: The new column is created but is filled with NaT.

Comment: Add `.fillna('')`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now it's filled with Nan... I'll think about a way to reformulate the problem.